# my component don't display

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use webpack and I have a problem with React. My component don't display and I have this problem that display:

> The resource at the address " http: // localhost:8080 / index.js " was
>   blocked(surrounded) because of a type(chap) incorrect MIME
>   (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Comment: It would help if you would post something regarding how this "resource" is referenced within your code.

Comment: Complementary to Mark, ... or which kind of resource is this.

Comment: Show your webpack output and the `request` and `response` headers for the request from the `inspect` window.

Comment: It's my webpack config: https://github.com/helenen/tattoo-react/blob/master/webpack.config.js